# go - print without space between items

Tags: go

```
fmt.Println("a","b")
```

I want to print the two strings without space padding, namely "ab", but the above will print "a b".

[Go fmt](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)

Do I just switch to using `Printf` ?

```
fmt.Printf("%s%s\n","a","b")
```

Comment: ```fmt.Println("ab")```

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk the starting premise is I have two strings rather than one. That said your "a"+"b" answer looks optimal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it can be found in the [doc](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println):

> Println formats using the default formats for its operands and writes
>   to standard output. **Spaces are always added** between operands and a
>   newline is appended. It returns the number of bytes written and any
>   write error encountered.

So you either need to do what you already said or you can concatenate the strings before printing:

`fmt.Println("a"+"b")`

Depending on your usecase you can use `strings.Join(myStrings, "")` for that purpose.

Comment: I wonder what the rationale was for making `Print` behave subtly differently to `Println` like this.

Answer (score 18):

Plain old print will work if you make the last element "\n".
It will also be easier to read if you aren't used to printf style formatting.

See here [on play](http://play.golang.org/p/Psyxvs_Nu8)

```
fmt.Println("a","b")
fmt.Print("a","b","\n")
fmt.Printf("%s%s\n","a","b")
```

will print:

```
a b
ab
ab
```

Comment: Don't forget `fmt.Println("a" + "b")`

Comment: fmt.Print("a","b","\n") may hard code the \n which may by operating system specific. E.g. DOS vs Linux. fmt.Println("a" + "b") might could get around that.

Answer (score 2):

Println relies on [`doPrint(args, true, true)`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/fmt/print.go?s=7558:7607#L1182), where first argument is `addspace` and second is `addnewline`. So Prinln ith multiple arguments will always print space.

It seems there is no call of `doPrint(args, false, true)` which is what you want. 
`Printf` may be a solution, `Print` also but you should add a newline.

Answer (score -1):

You'd have to benchmark to compare performance, but I'd rather use the following than a `Printf`:

```
fmt.Println(strings.Join([]string{"a", "b"}, ""))
```

Remember to `import "strings"`, and see [`strings.Join`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join) documentation for an explanation.

Comment: fmt.Print("a","b","\n") looks much more readable. One issue may be hard coding the \n which may by operating system specific. E.g. DOS vs Linux.

Answer (score -1):

the solution in my project

```
package main

import "fmt"

var formatMap = map[int]string{
    0: "",
    1: "%v",
}

func Println(v ...interface{}) {
    l := len(v)
    if s, isOk := formatMap[l]; !isOk {
        for i := 0; i < len(v); i++ {
            s += "%v"
        }
        formatMap[l] = s
    }
    s := formatMap[l] + "\n"
    fmt.Printf(s, v...)
}
func main() {
    Println()
    Println("a", "b")
    Println("a", "b")
    Println("a", "b", "c", 1)
}
```